# Where is the Linux source kept in a Rackspace Gentoo VPS?

Tags: gentoo, rackspace, linux-kernel, udev

I'm emerging `udev` and it complains it couldn't find the kernel sources under `/usr/src/linux` (there's nothing inside `/usr/src/` indeed). As a result, it tries to take the version from the currently running kernel and messes up thinking it's an older version than what it needs (when it actually isn't).

---

So where are the sources so that I can properly link to them? And could I have done something wrong for them not to be in the right place?

Comment: Have you tried asking Rackspace support?

Comment: -1, Vote to close - too localized. This is not a general server question but one VERY specific to a specific ISP and should be handled with their support as per site policies.

Answer (score 1):

Is this on Rackspace Cloud? I've had a similar issue on Slicehost and although, as far as I know, the sources for the actual kernel being run aren't available (well, at least not through Portage), I was able to just emerge the latest version of `gentoo-sources` and that was enough to allow the package to be installed.

Ben's comment is right, though, this would be a better issue to take up on the forums or with the support team.

Answer (score 1):

Just install one of the kernels [which are in portage](http://gentoo-portage.com/sys-kernel). Out of the kernels provided in `sys-kernel` I'd take `sys-kernel/vanilla-sources` since you don't really want to run that kernel but only provide the sources.

Answer (score 0):

Check what kernel that you're using (`uname -a`) and if it's a Gentoo kernel, do what joschi said but merge `gentoo-sources`.

Answer (score 0):

If you’re running 2.6.32.12 or newer, the Slicehost/Rackspace Cloud kernel source code — they use the same kernels — is available from Slicehost’s website.

See [Slicehost’s kernel source article](http://articles.slicehost.com/2010/6/18/downloading-and-using-kernel-source-code-2-6-32-12-and-newer-on-gentoo) for the link and more information. (I’d link to the download site directly, but I don’t have the reputation yet. Someone feel free to edit it in.)

You didn’t do anything wrong — it’s not installed by default.